# Getting a translate relative to a different matrix

Tags: c++, augmented-reality

I have an AR application, and two trackers recognised by the camera. I have an object appear on each, their position is set by transforming their matrix (matrix *  trackerMatrix). Tracker location transform is technically relative to the camera.

What I'm trying to do is have Tracker A in the scene, bring in Tracker B, an object appears on Tracker B, and then have object's position changed to be relative the the tracker A instead, so tracker B can leave the scene.

I initially thought I can make a vector, target - position, and then replace the objects location with tracker A's, minus the vector. But I must be wrong as that does not work no matter how I twist it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the object position is initially described by `worldToCamera * cameraToTrackerB * objectPositionRelativeToTrackerB`, you can get the object position relative to trackerA as `currentObjectPositionRelativeToTrackerA = inv(cameraToTrackerA) * cameraToTrackerB * objectPositionRelativeToTrackerB`.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!